# Simulate .stl mesh in Gazebo

Tags: sdformat, gazebo-1.3

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello,

I am new at Gazebo/ROS integration tool and I am using ROS groovy with Gazebo 1.3.
Yet I am just able to get my hands on sdf xml programming and exported my mesh in gazebo environment.

How should I handle my mesh model to get it running? Should I import part by part?

roslaunch gazebo_worlds empty_world.launch

rosrun gazebo spawn_model -file model.sdf -gazebo -z 200 -model my_robot

Any help regarding this will be appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/1839/simulate-.stl-mesh-in-gazebo/) by [skhan](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/266/skhan/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 131 on 2013-03-15

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi,

[Here](http://gazebosim.org/wiki/Tutorials/1.3/beginner/mesh_import) is a tutorial how to import a mesh in gazebo. You could also create an sdf model and import it in the *.world* file.

```
<include>
  <uri>model://mesh_model</uri>
  <pose>0 0 1 0 0 0</pose>
</include>
```

In order to load it save the *mesh_model* in *~/.gazebo/models* folder.

UPDATE

One link with many mesh collisions visuals:

```
    <model name="my_mesh_one_link">
      <link name="mesh_link">

        <visual name="visual1">
          <geometry>
            <mesh><uri>file://my_mesh1.dae</uri></mesh>
          </geometry>
        </visual>
        <collision name="collision1">
          <geometry>
            <mesh><uri>file://my_mesh1.dae</uri></mesh>
          </geometry>
        </collision>

        <visual name="visual2">
          <geometry>
            <mesh><uri>file://my_mesh2.dae</uri></mesh>
          </geometry>
        </visual>
        <collision name="collision2">
          <geometry>
            <mesh><uri>file://my_mesh2.dae</uri></mesh>
          </geometry>
        </collision>

      </link>
    </model>
```

For every mesh a different link:

```
    <model name="my_mesh_many_links">

      <link name="mesh_link1">
        <visual name="visual1">
          <geometry>
            <mesh><uri>file://my_mesh1.dae</uri></mesh>
          </geometry>
        </visual>
        <collision name="collision1">
          <geometry>
            <mesh><uri>file://my_mesh1.dae</uri></mesh>
          </geometry>
        </collision>
      </link>

      <link name="mesh_link2">
        <visual name="visual2">
          <geometry>
            <mesh><uri>file://my_mesh2.dae</uri></mesh>
          </geometry>
        </visual>
        <collision name="collision2">
          <geometry>
            <mesh><uri>file://my_mesh2.dae</uri></mesh>
          </geometry>
        </collision>
      </link>

    </model>
```

With the later model you can add joints between the links. If you want them to behave statically between them use only one link.

Cheers,
Andrei

---

Originally posted by [AndreiHaidu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/87/andreihaidu/) with karma: 2108 on 2013-03-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [skhan](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/266/skhan/) on 2013-03-15**:
@AndreiHaidu
Thanks, I am aware of it that how I import it but for simulation I have to import part by part or whole design?

**Comment by [AndreiHaidu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/87/andreihaidu/) on 2013-03-15**:
Well, you can either create for every mesh file a link, and then add joints between the links. Or if you want all the pieces in a single link, then you just add more collisions and visuals. I updated the answer with an example. Hope it helps :)

**Comment by [skhan](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/266/skhan/) on 2013-03-20**:
Thanks I try this approach

**Comment by [IsaacS](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/15/isaacs/) on 2014-11-15**:
Tutorial URL moved to http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=import_mesh&cat=build_robot